# Change standand MySQL query to 'prepared' MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with changing a 'standard' MySQL query into a prepared statement to prevent SQL Injection etc.

Below is the code which is giving me errors,

The 2nd SQL query is the one I am trying to get working,
(The one that is not commented out)

```
    <?php 
include('../db_connect.inc');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashedPassword = md5($password);






//$query = $conn->query("Select * from dog_parks.members where username = '$username' and password ='$hashedPassword' ");
//$count = $query->rowcount();
//$row = $query->fetch();


$query = $conn->prepare("Select * from dog_parks.members where username = :username_login and password = :password_login ");
$query->bindParam(':username_login', $username);
$query->bindParam(':password_login', $hashedPassword);
$count = $query->rowcount();
$row = $query->fetch();
$query->execute();







if ($count > 0){
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['username'];
header('location:home.php');
}   else {
?>
<script>
    alert("Incorrect Details. Check your User Name or Password.")
    window.location="../index.php";
</script>
<?php 
}
?>
```

After executing the following code i get the JavaScript alert saying incorrect password, this would be due to not meeting the first condition in the if statement

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I think all you need to do is change 1 letter. let me know if my answer worked.

Comment: Actually I found another error, try now

Comment: try now, the final edit has been made lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counting row function is with a capital 'c': `rowCount()`. Also your code is in the wrong order. use the following:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("Select * from dog_parks.members where username = :username_login and password = :password_login ");
$query->bindParam(':username_login', $username);
$query->bindParam(':password_login', $hashedPassword);
$query->execute();
$count = $query->rowCount();
$row = $query->fetch();
```

Let me know if that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I do my prepare statements as followed(based off your code):

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = :username");
$query->execute(array(':username' => $username));
$queryRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I find it easier to throw it in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = $conn->prepare("Select * from dog_parks.members where username = :username_login and password = :password_login ", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$query->execute(array(':username_login' => $username, ':password_login' => $hashedPassword));
```

Comment: Hi I am using PDO, what do I need to get the prepared statement working with PDO syntax?

Comment: Updated, try the answer above.